# Making Dropdown Menu User Inputs Mutually Exclusive In Pine

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a set of user inputs as follows:

```
//Entry Indicator Selection

tog_entry1 = input.string(title="Entry Indicator 1", defval="KST", group="Entry Indicators", options=["KRI", "KST", "Supertrend", "None"])
tog_entry2 = input.string(title="Entry Indicator 2", defval="None", group="Entry Indicators", options=["KRI", "KST", "Supertrend", "None"])
tog_entry3 = input.string(title="Entry Indicator 3", defval="None", group="Entry Indicators", options=["KRI", "KST", "Supertrend", "None"])
```

[image: Indicator Options]

The idea is to allow users to pick up to three entry indicators from a bank of options. At the moment, the options are not mutually exclusive - e.g., the user could pick "Supertrend", "Supertrend", "Supertrend", and so on.

Using Pine, Is there any way to eliminate options that have already been selected from the remaining lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

If you want to prevent users selecting the same input options, you can throw a runtime error with the `runtime.error()` function.

```
if (tog_entry1 == tog_entry2) or (tog_entry1 == tog_entry3) or (tog_entry2 == tog_entry3)
    runtime.error("You cannot select same indicators")
```